# Where to put the jQuery messages?

Tags: jquery, drupal

I have a form on my website (based on Drupal), 
and I've added a JS to it, now I have some messages like 
Hints on input keydown. 
I was wondering, where should I keep those messages 
(since I don't want them to be stored in each individual JS file 
that I'll be making from now on - but in one central place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a js file for that effect, using a map to identify the strings?

```
var strings = { "SaveAsHint": "Will save the project with a different name",
                "OpenHint": "Opens a new project",
                "...": "Keep on going"
              }
```

Then you include this file and reference `strings["SaveAsHint"]` in your code.

Another alternative would be to store them in a database and use a callback to return this structure from the server (or, if you can afford it, use the local browser database in HTML5, filling it up once at application startup)